# Maven Cobertura Ignore Trivial from Commandline

Tags: maven, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

Hello Guys is there any way to set ignore Trival True (Cobertura) from Commandline?

Pom Example:

```html
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<configuration>
  <instrumentation>
    <ignoreTrivial>true</ignoreTrivial>                 
  </instrumentation>
</configuration>
```

```
mvn verify javadoc:javadoc cobertura:cobertura -DignoreTrivial=true -Dinstrumentation.DignoreTrivial=true -Dcobertura.report.format=xml findbugs:findbugs -l output.log"
```

i tried  `DignoreTrivial` and `Dinstrumentation.DignoreTrivial` both  dont work

any suggestions?

I want to generate Test-Covarage Files but it should ignore getter/setter/constructor etc

ty in advance

Comment: I do not see any configuration which is named `ignoreTrivial` https://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html#Instrumentation

Comment: https://ganeshgembali.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/tip-exclude-trivial-getterssettersconstructors-from-cobertura-code-coverage-report/